# How do i form a polynomial equation given the details provided?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

My question: Write down a polynomial in $x$ which gives the remainder $3$ when it is divided by each of the following: $(x+1) (x-2) (x+3)$. What exactly does this mean? I know it wanted me to use the details provided to form an equation but how? From how i interpreted the questions, i have got $p(-1)=3, p(2)=3,p(-3)=3$. Is this the right first step? and how do I proceed with the next step? Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A polynomial $p(x)$ gives a reminder $r(x)$ upon dividing by $q(x)$ if there exists a polynomial $m(x)$ such that

$$p(x) = m(x)q(x) + r(x)$$

(sometimes you also want that $\deg r(x) \leq \deg q(x)$).

Anyway in your case there exist $m_1(x),m_2(x),m_3(x)$ such that

$$p(x) = m_1(x)(x+1)+3$$
$$p(x)= m_2(x)(x-2)+3$$
$$p(x) = m_3(x) (x+3)+3$$

In particular $(x+1)(x-2)(x+3)$ divides $p(x)-3$ this happens for example when

$$p(x) = (x+1)(x-2)(x+3)+3$$

Comment: first of all thanks for answering! However, I still have a question. I get that p(x) has a relationship between the quotient, the divider and the remainder. But what do you mean by $m1(x),m2(x),m3(x)$ exist? From the general form you have shown me, you replaced the $(x-1$ etc into the quotient $q(x)$ but not $m(x)$? And i could not understand what you meant in 2nd last line. Thank you and sorry.

Comment: @Tfue The definition in the first line says that if the reminder of $p(x)$ by $q(x)$ is, say $3$. Then there exists a polynomial $m(x)$ such that $p(x)=m(x)q(x)+3$. I just applied that for $q(x)=(x+1)$, $q(x)=(x-2)$ and $q(x)=x+3$. (This is similar to numbers, the reminder of $13$ by $3$ is $1$ because there exists $m=4$ such that $13=4\cdot 3 + 1$.)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

$$p(x) = (x+1)(x-2)(x+3)+3$$